# symfony 5 , Doctrine Lifecycle Listeners not running

Tags: php, symfony

I try a Doctrine Lifecycle Listeners create but he don't execute the dump.
i have created a entity, a listener and update service.yml

it's crazy ;-)

i have:
in services.yaml

```
  App\EventListener\TestOrmListener:
    tags:
      - { name: doctrineormtester,event: postPersist, entity: 'App\Entity\Galery'}
```

in src/EventListener/TestOrmListener.php

```
<?php
namespace App\EventListener;

use App\Entity\Galery;
use Doctrine\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

class TestOrmListener
{
    // the listener methods receive an argument which gives you access to
    // both the entity object of the event and the entity manager itself
    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args): void
    {
        $entity = $args->getObject();

        // if this listener only applies to certain entity types,
        // add some code to check the entity type as early as possible
        if (!$entity instanceof Galery) {
            return;
        }

        $entityManager = $args->getObjectManager();
        dump($entityManager);
        die('mick');
        // ... do something with the Product entity
    }
}
```

an in the Entity Galery

```
    <?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\GaleryRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use App\Entity\Traits\Timestampable;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=GaleryRepository::class)
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Galery
{
    use Timestampable;
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nom;
```

Do you have a idea?

Comment: I guess you have a typo in listener's tags.

Comment: i have a error in services.yaml but the listener don't run

Comment: Try to fix your listener tags definition, it could help to trigger your listener on doctrine lifecycle events.
- { name: 'doctrine.orm.entity_listener', event: 'postPersist', entity: 'App\Entity\Galery'}

Comment: @eldino and how it ended? Was my answer helpful or you found another solution? Please leave some response for future readers.

Comment: ok i write a comment, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem in your tag section.
According to the official [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#creating-an-event-listener):

> The next step is to enable the Doctrine listener in the Symfony application by creating a new service for it and tagging it with the doctrine.event_listener tag

So your service definition should look like this:

```
App\EventListener\TestOrmListener:
        tags:
            - { name: 'doctrine.event_listener', event: 'postPersist', entity: 'App\Entity\Galery' }
```

Comment: I also tested it on my own project (with your listener) and it works

Comment: thanks for your help @Karol Dabrowski